# Вывод массива в строку при рефлексии

Tags: java, рефлексия

Суть вопроса вот в чем. Есть некий класс:

```
public class TestClass {
    private static final int i = 9;
    private int[] array = {1, 4, 9};
    private Object[] array2 = {new Date(), new Date()};
}
```

Далее делаем следующее:

```
Field[] fields = TestClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    System.out.println(field.get(new TestClass()));
}
```

Тут мы получаем массив, в котором лежат поля нашего класса. Далее нам нужно вывести значения этих полей. Но если у нас поле - массив, тогда нужно вывести все элементы этого массива, а не ссылку. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) умеет выводить массивы любой размерности и, если нет жестких требований к формату, можно написать коротко и без рефлексии:

```
Object value = field.get(new TestClass());
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(new Object[]{value}));
```

Этот код будет поддерживать массивы любой размерности (`String[][]`, `int[][][]`). Вывод будет таким:

```
[9]
[[1, 4, 9]]
[[Fri Mar 30 13:06:50 GMT 2018, Fri Mar 30 13:06:50 GMT 2018]]
```

При необходимости лишние квадратные скобки можно обрезать:

```
Object value = field.get(new TestClass());
String valueText = Arrays.deepToString(new Object[]{value});
valueText = valueText.substring(1, valueText.length()-1);
System.out.println(valueText);
```

Этот способ не подойдет если требуется свой формат для вывода или если нужно будет не выводить, а как-то иначе обрабатывать полученный массив. В этом случае нужно будет использовать рефлексию ([см. ответ @Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807120/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8/807138#807137)) и, если нужно поддерживать многомерные массивы, рекурсию.

Похожее обсуждение на английском с вариантами обработки различных массивов и обманчивым заголовком: [How to see if an object is an array without using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725533/how-to-see-if-an-object-is-an-array-without-using-reflection)

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    private static final int i = 9;
    private int[] array = {1, 4, 9};
    private Object[] array2 = {new Date(), new Date()};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main obj = new Main();

        for (Field field : Main.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType().isArray()) {
                Object array = field.get(obj);
                int length = Array.getLength(array);
                System.out.print("[");
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (i != 0)
                        System.out.print(", ");
                    System.out.print(Array.get(array, i));
                }
                System.out.println("]");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(field.get(obj));            
            }
        }
    }
}
```